# ReactJS : How to useParams?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Im kinda struggling with a simple filter method on ReactJS.

Whenever I use the useParams it brokes my filter function.

I find no documentation/tutorials without incrementations or buttons about useEffect & useState.

I hope anyone can help, thanks.

**Details.js**

```
const Details = () => {

 const Employees = [
 {
   name: "Platon",
   id: 1
 },
 {
   name: "Solane",
   id: 2
 },
 {
   name: "Sedal",
   id: 3
 }
 ]

const foundEmployee = Employees.find((Employee) => {
 return Employee.name === 'Platon'
})

console.log(foundEmployee) // returns "Platon"

return (
   <div></div>
 )
}

export default Details;
```

**Details.js** with useParams

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navigation = () => {

 let name = useParams()
 console.log(name) // returns "Platon"

 const Employees = [
   {
     name: "Platon",
     id: 1
   },
   {
     name: "Solane",
     id: 2
   },
   {
     name: "Sedal",
     id: 3
   }
   ]

 const foundEmployee = Employees.find((Employee) => {
   return Employee.name === name
 })
 
 console.log(foundEmployee) // returns Undefined
 
 return (
     <div></div>
   )
 }
 

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: When you console log in the body of a function component as an unintentional side-effect you're bound to have unintentional results. I suspect you should be seeing several logs, eventually with the `name` value you expect. Where are you using an `useEffect` hook? Is this your complete code?

Comment: I've been trying to add useEffect, but I cant for now. I think the code is more clear and understandable like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `useParams` returns key-value pairs. Maybe destructuring it will help? Like this:

`let { name } = useParams()` instead of `let name = useParams()`

Comment: @pedrofromperu How did `let name = useParams()` correctly output "Platon" then? Were you seeing the nested property and thought it correct?

Comment: Im not sure to understand your question. I dont see the nested property. Im on ReactJS for less than 10 days, sorry. 
But I can assure that console.log(name) gave me the "name" without specifying me it was a key-pair value.

Answer (score 0):

useParams() let you access the parameters of the current route

to access parameters using useParams() you need to destructure.

```
let {name} = useParams() // access name paramter of the current route
let {id} = useParams() //access id parameter of the current route .
```